# ionic vue ion-back-button is not working as expectation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs2

I am trying to use back button to go on previous page butt unfortunately it is not working. It is not giving any error.

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>  
</ion-buttons>
```

do I need to call any kind of js code?

In documentation I didn't see that https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button?_gl=1*1exs5lk*_ga*MTM2Nzc2ODQwNi4xNjEyMTYyNDU0*_ga_REH9TJF6KF*MTYxMzg5NzIwNi4yMi4xLjE2MTM4OTc0MzEuMA..

Comment: What are you routing with? In case you got an SPA thats misconfigured, it's likely that there is no "back" at all - does the browser-back button work for you? Are there any outputs in the console regarding misbehaviour?

Comment: this is ionic hyprid app. browser back button is working fine . there is no error in console

Comment: Does the network-tab show any actions when pressing the button?

Comment: Not at all. nothing happening there

Comment: why are you using `defaultHref`?

Comment: I see the documentation thery were using it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was my bad I didn't import the IonBackButton component and was directly using it

```
import { IonBackButton } from "@ionic/vue";
```